# If $A=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}2&1\\-4&-2\\\end{array}}\right]$ and $I$ is a $2\times 2$identity matrix Find the value of $I+2A+3A^2+....$

Tags: matrices

> If $A=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}2&1\\-4&-2\\\end{array}}\right]$ and $I=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&1\\\end{array}}\right]$ Find the value of $I+2A+3A^2+....$

My answer to this question is

$=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}5&2\\-8&-3\\\end{array}}\right]$

Am I right?

Comment: the matrix is nilpotent. Find its nilpotenzindex. Then can you conclude that almost all terms of this matriy polynomial equation are zero

Answer (score 5):

As $A^2=0$, then $I+2A+3A^2+\cdots=I+2A$ which is what you have as your answer.

Comment: then I guess I am right then.